# Using openshift images in opensourse product under Apache License 2.0?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Can I use openshift/origin docker images (openshift/origin, openshift/jenkins-slave-nodejs-centos7, centos/s2i-base-centos7), that are released under GPLv2, to build docker images in my software, if I want to release it under Apache License 2.0?

Comment: Where are you seeing it said that images such as ``openshift/origin`` are released under the GPLv2. The license file in the ``openshift/origin`` repo on GitHub has an Apache license. https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Yes, you are right. But docker image openshift/origin has label org.label-schema.license=GPLv2.

Comment: I would suggest you ask about it on one of the lists at https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo That label may ultimately be coming from a generic OS base image.